# Using session.socket.io for message notifications. Does it work with POST requests?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

So I have this web app, and I want it to send a notification to a user with socket.io when they get a massage.

I've got my app.js file with this code in it:

```
exports.sessionSockets = new SessionSockets(exports.io, sessionStore, cookieParser);

app.get('/foo', home.foo);
app.post('/bar', home.bar);
```

And home.js:

```
exports.foo = function(req, res){
  exports.sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('session', session);
  });

  res.render('foo');
}

exports.bar = function(req, res){
  exports.sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('session', session);
  });
  res.send(200);
}
```

The first function, exports.foo works fine. The second one, exports.bar, does not. I never see any output to the console. Is there a way to make this work? Or am I going about it wrong?

Edit: added a res.send statement. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First guess is the fact that `exports.bar` never responds properly to the HTTP POST request is screwing things up. Put some kind of response in there, `res.send(200)` or whatever, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: It does respond. All the other code I put in the function executes.

Comment: You never invoke any methods on the `res` object. Your HTTP (not the web socket, the POST) never responds.